# FindsBy not assigning value to variable

Tags: c#, selenium

I've only just discovered 'findsBy' in the page model, and I'm trying to get it working for a page. I'm having difficulty getting the value I derive using the 'FindsBy' assign to the variable I'm creating.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "viewMenu")]
private IWebElement ViewMenuLink;

//define functions to click elements on the page
public void ClickViewMenu()
{ ViewMenuLink.Click(); }
```

I see an error stating field ViewMenuLink is never assigned to and will always have its default value null. Am I missing something obvious here? My understanding of 'FindsBy' usage is that the value of that would be assigned to 'ViewMenuLink'. Thanks in advance of any pointers!

Comment: Can you update the Question with the HTML of the element?

Comment: <a class="auth-home-link dropdown-toggle" id="viewMenu" href="#"    data-toggle="dropdown">View</a>

Comment: However the error occurs in visual studio before the test has even run. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern is to use PageFactory.InitElements to initialise all variables tagged with FindsBy - this would usually be placed in the constructor:

```
public MyPage(IWebDriver d)
{
     this.driver = d;
     PageFactory.InitElements(d, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyTester, this is what I was missing.